# Send and receive UDP Messages simultaneously

Tags: linux, bash, sockets

Can UDP messages be sent and received in the same bash script using netcat?

In Linux I want to send a UDP message and receive its output in a variable for further processing. Ideally I want to do this in bash using netcat but I'm open to other possibilities (Java should be easy but I dont want to install additional components if I can avoid it)

So far I can issue the command `echo -ne 'some data' | nc -u 192.168.0.xyz 9760` and see the incoming signals by setting up a listener `nc -ul 9761` in another window. But the question is how can this be done in one process, and have the output assigned to a variable?

Could the listener process be sent to the background at the start of a script? if so how is this destroyed when the process finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can background the listener, something like this:

```
nc -ul 9761 >/tmp/foo &
echo -ne 'some data' | nc -u 192.168.0.xyz 9760
wait # waits for the backgrounded command to complete
data=$(</tmp/foo)
```

Comment: That works well... How would you clean up the process afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

You can write short scripts using Socket Programming. You need to create a Socket and add UDP properties on one Device and on the other device wait for incoming UDP message. Principally the messages are received as a string but you can save it to a string variable and do further modifications.

```
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) //create socket 
sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slength) //sender
recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slength) //receiver
```

Ofcourse you need to assign some other properties to the socket parameters.
Take a look at this [Website](http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-c-linux/). It has been Explained in simple words how you can program a client server scenario that communicate through udp over IP.